# Как скрыть сообщение с inline кнопками после нажатие на них? Python aiogram dot telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как удалить сообщение с инлайн кнопками при нажатии на одну из них ,чтоб сообщение не весело выше?

```
import aiogram
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, \
    CallbackQuery
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

TOKEN = ""

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
ib1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="ccылки", callback_data='url')
ib2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="2", url='' )
ikb.add(ib1, ib2)


ikb_url =InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

ib1_url = InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", url='')
ib2_url = InlineKeyboardButton(text="2", url='')
ikb_url.add(ib1_url, ib2_url)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(f"приветствие")
    kb = [

        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text="начать работу")
        ]
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=kb,
        resize_keyboard=True,
        one_time_keyboard=True 
    )
    await message.answer(f"навигация чтото за помощь", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "начать работу")
async def with_puree(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(
        f'выбирай',
        reply_markup=ikb,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

[image: вот]

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
await message.edit_reply_markup()
```